# Functions in construct statement

Tags: php, function, if-statement, construct

I am just coding something and wanted to know how I can include a function in a construct.

```
if (!formatPhone($phone) && !empty($phone)) {
    $e = 1;
    $e_message .= '<li>The phone number is invalid, please use the format (000) 000-0000.</li>';
} else {
    $phone = formatPhone($phone);
}
```

Can I assign $phone to the `formatePhone()` output directly in the contruct statement, but still check for a `return false;`?

Comment: I assume you mean construct as a synonym of assign?

Comment: It would be useful to know what the `formatPhone()` function does and returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include an assignment as expression. But in your case you should reorder the test, to check first for emptiness before the value gets reassigned:

```
if ( !empty($phone) and !($phone = formatPhone($phone)) ) {
    $e = 1;
    $e_message .= '<li>The phone number is invalid, please use the format (000) 000-0000.</li>';
}
```

This would save you the else tree. But more readable this is not. :|

Answer (score 1):

```
$phone = formatPhone($phone) or $phone = $default_value;
```

This means that if the return value of `formatPhone()` is false, `$phone` will get assigned `$default_value` instead of false. Otherwise, if the return value of `formatPhone()` is not false then `$phone` will be assigned its return value.

Comment: @mario `or` has a lower precedence than `=` (from what I remember).  So it will be evaluated after.  Parenthesis could be added appropriately.  If `formatPhone($phone)` returns false, `$phone` is set to `false` and then to `$default_value` immediately after.

Comment: @Matt: My comment was for the original post. (Which was silently changed now...) - Still not really an answer for OPs case though.

Comment: @mario Okay then that makes sense (confusing when things get edited after you post)